# Pointer capture and release in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-rt

In a test app, I've created 3 Grid objects named `grid1`, `grid2` and `grid3` that each contains
a `Border` and an `Image`. For example, `grid1` is defined in `xaml` as:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" 
      Grid.Column="0" 
      Margin="10"
      Name="grid1"
      Tag="0" 
      PointerPressed="grid_PointerPressed" 
      PointerReleased="grid_PointerReleased"    
      PointerExited="grid_PointerExited" 
      PointerEntered="grid_PointerEntered">

      <Border CornerRadius="10" 
              BorderThickness="2" 
              BorderBrush="Black"
              Name="border1" Background="{StaticResource CellBackgroundColorDefault}"/>
      <Image Name="cell1" Source="" Margin="10" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Grid>
```

Each image gets its source programmatically when the page loads. The functions grid_PointerPressed, grid_PointerReleased etc are the same for grid1, grid2 and grid3. The grid objects are inside another grid, with some space between them. When a finger presses a grid and its contents, I give the grid's border another background color. When the finger releases the grid, then the background gets its default color, the grid animates its contents, and a sound is played, e.g

```
private void grid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
      Grid g = sender as Grid;
      int index = Int32.Parse(g.Tag as string);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("[Pressing {0}?]", index));
      if (g.PointerCaptures == null || g.PointerCaptures.Count == 0)
      {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("\tAccepted", index));
               LoadSoundAndPlay(index);
               ChangeCellBackground(index);
               g.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
      }
}

private void grid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Grid g = sender as Grid;
        int index = Int32.Parse(g.Tag as string);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("[Releasing {0}?]", index));
        if (g.PointerCaptures != null && g.PointerCaptures.Count > 0)
        {
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("\tAccepted", index));
              ChangeCellBackgroundToDefault(index);
              AnimateCell(index);
              g.ReleasePointerCapture(e.Pointer);
        }
}
```

Now, because a touch can press `grid1`, stay pressed, move out of `grid1`, enter `grid2`, and release when in `grid2`, I've also added pointer events when entering and exiting:

```
private void grid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
            Grid g = sender as Grid;
            int index = Int32.Parse(g.Tag as string);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("[Exiting {0}?]", index));
            if (g.PointerCaptures != null && g.PointerCaptures.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("\tAccepted", index));
                ChangeCellBackgroundToDefault(index);
                AnimateCell(index);
                g.ReleasePointerCapture(e.Pointer);
            }
}

private void grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
            Grid g = sender as Grid;
            int index = Int32.Parse(g.Tag as string);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("[Entering {0}?]", index));
            if (g.PointerCaptures == null || g.PointerCaptures.Count == 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("\tAccepted", index));
                LoadSoundAndPlay(index);
                ChangeCellBackground(index);
                g.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
            }
}
```

Everything works OK, but there is one problem which I can't solve- If I touch the first grid, keep my finger pressed, and very quickly move my finger to the last grid (passing through the second grid) and then releasing, the following messages are printed:

```
[Entering 0?]
    Accepted
[Pressing 0?]
    Accepted
[Exiting 0?]
    Accepted
***Animating 0***
[Exiting 1?]
[Entering 2?]
    Accepted
[Releasing 2?]
    Accepted
***Animating 2***
[Exiting 2?]
```

The numbers 0, 1 and 2 correspond to the Grid Tags. As you can see, there was no event **PointeredEntered** for the second grid (Tag: 1) and so it was not animated, and no sound was played for it. However, if I do the same thing slowly, then everything works OK.

How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: I had an issue a while ago that I believe being related to this one. The ManipulationDelta event didn't fire if you did a quick movement. Later I realised it was not an issue of it being quick, rather it was an issue of it being.... "continuous". If you have a steady and continuous movement ManipulationDelta won't fire. I guess that is related to your problem and would be glad if someone had an explanation to it.

Comment: In my case, the problem does not appear when moving slowly, neither when moving quickly only between two Grid objects.